# Why is this question downvoted?

Tags: discussion

I don't know why someone downvoted. The similar question? But I have already reviewed, this is not the same. Maybe someone think this is a virus, I'm true it is not. It's only my test. The program is not an actual product. If it is useful to user is the thing for product manager. I am only exploring

My question is：[Android：how to disable HOME button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138387/androidhow-to-disable-home-button)

Comment: Repeating "I use this method，but it doesn't work." over and over again doesn't help..

Comment: this is edited later，because i can't post it as describe is short。first it doesn't exist.

Comment: If your post was too short, you needed to add more detail to your question. "This doesn't work" is not a question. What did you expect it to do? How did it fail? What else did you try?

Comment: Why do you put such odd Unicode characters into the text? Is that a mistake?

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby: The OP is clearly not a native english speaker. Most probably his native language uses a script that lies far outside ASCII, and the accompanying input methods make it easy to use those characters. Add in that then typing in a very foreign (to the OP) character set makes it easy to make mistakes, and I can see that strange characters (to us) creep into a posting.

Comment: That question has been asked on SO many times, you need to do little search before posting a question.

Comment: those are double-byte punctuations btw

Answer (score 10):

I ask this question，but it doesn't upvote。 I ask this question，but it doesn't upvote。 I ask this question，but it doesn't upvote。 I ask this question，but it doesn't upvote。 I ask this question，but it doesn't upvote。

Comment: [Painful.](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12138387/1)

Comment: what do you want to express???

Answer (score 8):

Quote from the downvote-tooltip:

> This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful.

Or maybe it is the repeating of one sentence so that your question gets accepted by the system...maybe it's the lack of formatting in the code...or maybe it's the block of code without any commenting...or it's the missing overall information, like version of Android or what happens when you run it...or it's the misformed title (don't put tags into the title)...

Also...you have very odd Unicode characters in there...stop that...please...